# Javascript: array of objects, group/restructure objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The following object contains a list of recipients and subscriptions, I wish to create a new array with a different structure such as below.

> [{"recipientId":"13251376",
> "services":"3218143,15656200,3721"},{"recipientId":"13251316",
> "services":"3218143"}

```js
let serviceSubscriptions =  [{"recipientId":"13251316","serviceId":"3218143"},{"recipientId":"13251376","serviceId":"3218143"},{"recipientId":"13251376","serviceId":"15656200"},{"recipientId":"13251376","serviceId":"3721"}]

let testArr = [];

serviceSubscriptions.forEach(serviceSubscriptions => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(serviceSubscriptions)) {
    //console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    testArr.push(`${key}:${value}`);
    
  }
});
console.log(testArr);
```

Here is a list of things I've tried - https://jsfiddle.net/v5azdysg/2/

**update 30/11/22 19:08**
I am trying to integrate @Mr. Polywhirl  your answer with my idea, but I cannot get far as I am not skilled in this area, here is what I have so far. https://jsfiddle.net/aectk8v1/4/ What I need is to add a new key called essentially services/subscriptions with the list of ids of the subscriptions, but this should be appended to the existing list of keys and also a key which shows if subscriptions exist, true or false, on the other hand another version I need is to list all the services keys and add the value of true or false under a single key such as `"subscriptions":{12345:true,123456:false}`

```js
;let recipients = [
{"id":"666777","lawfulBasis":"0","jurisdiction":"AMER","name":"David G"},
{"id":"888999","lawfulBasis":"1","jurisdiction":"ASIA","name":"Mike A"},
{"id":"444555","lawfulBasis":"2","jurisdiction":"EUR","name":"John No Sub"}
];

let serviceSubscriptions =  [
{"recipientId":"666777","serviceId":"3218143"},
{"recipientId":"666777","serviceId":"8956799"},
{"recipientId":"888999","serviceId":"15656200"},
{"recipientId":"000000","serviceId":"3721"}
];


/* return subscribed */
//.map method creates new array populated with result of call
//.some performs test true|false
// ... dot notation copies all parts from 1 array to another merge/join

   var result = recipients.map(Obj1 => {
    

        return { ...Obj1, 
                        isSubscribed:serviceSubscriptions.some(Obj2 => Obj1.id == Obj2.recipientId),
                services1:serviceSubscriptions.map(Obj2 => Obj1.id == Obj2.recipientId),
                services:serviceSubscriptions.map(Obj2 => Obj2.serviceId),
       }
    });
    
  console.log(result)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce each item into a `Map<String, Set<String>>`. After you have the map, you can map the entries to objects where you join the `serviceId` arrays.

```js
const serviceSubscriptions =  [
  { "recipientId": "13251316", "serviceId": "3218143"  },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "3218143"  },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "15656200" },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "3721"     }
];

const testArr = [
  ...serviceSubscriptions
    .reduce((acc, { recipientId, serviceId }) =>
      acc.set(recipientId,
        (acc.get(recipientId) ?? new Set).add(serviceId)), new Map)
    .entries()
  ]
  .map(([recipientId, serviceIds]) => ({
    recipientId,
    services: [...serviceIds].join(',')
  }));

console.log(testArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is an alternative version that uses `Object` and `Array` types instead of `Map` and `Set` types.

**Note:** This performs worse than the version above, because it uses spreading which mutates the accumulator and service array values. This should be avoided.

```js
const serviceSubscriptions =  [
  { "recipientId": "13251316", "serviceId": "3218143"  },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "3218143"  },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "15656200" },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "3721"     }
];

const testArr = Object
  .entries(serviceSubscriptions
    .reduce((acc, { recipientId, serviceId }) => ({
      ...acc,
      [recipientId]: [...(acc[recipientId] ?? []), serviceId]
    }), {}))
  .map(([recipientId, serviceIds]) => ({
    recipientId,
    services: serviceIds.join(',')
  }));

console.log(testArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Efficiency

Here is the most efficient way possible. This algorithm is **O(*n*)** instead of **O(*2n*)** as seen in the preceding approaches.

```js
const serviceSubscriptions =  [
  { "recipientId": "13251316", "serviceId": "3218143"  },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "3218143"  },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "15656200" },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "3721"     }
];

const testArr = [], idLookup = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < serviceSubscriptions.length; i++) {
  const sub = serviceSubscriptions[i];
  if (!idLookup.has(sub.recipientId)) {
    idLookup.set(sub.recipientId, testArr.length);
    testArr.push({
      recipientId: sub.recipientId,
      services: sub.serviceId
    });
  } else {
    const index = idLookup.get(sub.recipientId);
    testArr[index].services += `,${sub.serviceId}`
  }
}

console.log(testArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

And here is a function version, of the code above:

```js
const serviceSubscriptions =  [
  { "recipientId": "13251316", "serviceId": "3218143"  },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "3218143"  },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "15656200" },
  { "recipientId": "13251376", "serviceId": "3721"     }
];

const reducer = (arr, keyFn, valueFn, addFn, reducerFn) => {
  const result = [], idLookup = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i], key = keyFn(item), val = valueFn(item);
    if (!idLookup.has(key)) {
      idLookup.set(key, result.length);
      result.push(addFn(key, val));
    } else {
      const index = idLookup.get(key);
      reducerFn(result[index], val);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const testArr = reducer(
  serviceSubscriptions,
  ({ recipientId }) => recipientId,
  ({ serviceId }) => serviceId,
  (key, val) => ({ recipientId: key, services: val }),
  (existing, curr) => existing.services += `,${curr}`
);

console.log(testArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Final update

This should work for your updated data:

```js
const recipients = [
  { "id": "666777", "lawfulBasis": "0", "jurisdiction": "AMER", "name": "David G" },
  { "id": "888999", "lawfulBasis": "1", "jurisdiction": "ASIA", "name": "Mike A" },
  { "id": "444555", "lawfulBasis": "2", "jurisdiction": "EUR", "name": "John No Sub" }
];

const subscriptions =  [
  { "recipientId": "666777", "serviceId": "3218143" },
  { "recipientId": "666777", "serviceId": "8956799" },
  { "recipientId": "888999", "serviceId": "15656200" },
  { "recipientId": "000000", "serviceId": "3721" }
];

const serviceIds = subscriptions.map(({ serviceId }) => serviceId);

const result = recipients.map(({ id, ...rest }) => ({
  id,
  isSubscribed: subscriptions.some(({ recipientId }) => recipientId === id),
  ...rest,
  services: [...serviceIds],
  services1: subscriptions.map(({ recipientId }) => recipientId === id)
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Hi Mr Poly, I've updaed my question, I need to be able to append the key and list of values to another array containing the recipients, "services": "3218143,15656200,3721" I've added the structure, thank you so much for your support, I've been cracking my head for the alst 48 hours.

Comment: @DavidGarcia I added a final version that matches your updated data.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this, [Mr. Polywhirl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74619088/621827) is more elegant than the following (I haven't done the O() calc on it to determine efficiency vs this one), but a basic solution just needs to use a couple for loops.

One to get the elements and another to iterate over the array again starting from the next index to add the service ids. I just have an extra object to use as a map to check if we already handled the recipientId.

```js
let serviceSubscriptions =  [{"recipientId":"13251316","serviceId":"3218143"},{"recipientId":"13251376","serviceId":"3218143"},{"recipientId":"13251376","serviceId":"15656200"},{"recipientId":"13251376","serviceId":"3721"}]

let testArr = [];
const addedRecipients = {};

for(let i = 0; i < serviceSubscriptions.length; i++) {
  // Create a new object so we don't alter the original.
  const recipSub = Object.assign({}, serviceSubscriptions[i]);
  // `undefined` is false in JS so we can check a map if we already handled it.
  if (addedRecipients[recipSub.recipientId]) continue;
  
  addedRecipients[recipSub.recipientId] = true;
  
  for (let y = i + 1; y < serviceSubscriptions.length; y++) {
      if (serviceSubscriptions[y].recipientId === recipSub.recipientId) {
  recipSub.serviceId = recipSub.serviceId + ',' + serviceSubscriptions[y].serviceId;

  }
}
testArr.push(recipSub);
}
console.log(testArr);
console.log(serviceSubscriptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and efficient version:

```
let result = Object.create(null)

for (let s of serviceSubscriptions) {
    result[s.recipientId] = result[s.recipientId] ?? []
    result[s.recipientId].push(s.serviceId)
}    

for (let r in result)
    result[r] = result[r].join()
```

Not sure why you'd want these arrays joined though.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on this script but is not 100% correct, I'd like the services ids user is subscribed to under a list also. such as the key example `servicesExample2` . I've been trying to integrate the code from the answers but my lack of coding  is blocking me Mr. Polywhirl, Stephen Gilboy, gog

```js
;let recipients = [
{"id":"666777","lawfulBasis":"0","jurisdiction":"AMER","name":"David G"},
{"id":"888999","lawfulBasis":"1","jurisdiction":"ASIA","name":"Mike A"},
{"id":"444555","lawfulBasis":"2","jurisdiction":"EUR","name":"John No Sub"}
];

let serviceSubscriptions =  [
{"recipientId":"666777","serviceId":"3218143"},
{"recipientId":"666777","serviceId":"8956799"},
{"recipientId":"888999","serviceId":"15656200"},
{"recipientId":"000000","serviceId":"3721"}
];

const recipientObj = recipients.map(({id,isSubscribed,...recipient}) => {
  //if (isSubscribed === true) {
      return {
            id,
          isSubscribed: serviceSubscriptions.some(( subs ) => subs.recipientId ===id),          
          test:'test',
          services: serviceSubscriptions.map(({recipientId,serviceId}) => serviceId+':'+serviceSubscriptions.some(({serviceId}) => recipientId === id)),
          servicesExample2: '3218143,3218143',
          ...recipient,
          
        }
    //}
});

console.log(recipientObj)
```

I think also my structure for key `services` is wrong

```
  services: ["3218143:false", "8956799:false", "15656200:true", "3721:false"],
```

How can it make it the correc structure? like below

```
services: [{"3218143:false"}, {"8956799:false"}, {"15656200:true"},{"3721:false"}],
```

[image]

**UPDATE, FINAL VERSION**

```js
const result = recipients.map(recipient => {
  // Create an array of the recipient's subscription IDs
  const subscriptionIds = serviceSubscriptions
    .filter(subscription => subscription.recipientId === recipient.id)
    .map(subscription => subscription.serviceId);

  return {
    ...recipient,
    isSubscribed: subscriptionIds.some(i=>i),
        services: subscriptionIds,
        servicesMatrix: serviceSubscriptions.map(({recipientId,serviceId}) => serviceId+':'+serviceSubscriptions.some(({serviceId}) => recipientId === recipient.id)),
  };
});

console.log(result);
```